# Invalid Column Names and An Expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected

Tags: sql-server

In query 3 and 4 I'm getting the following errors. For 3 my `SupplierID` and `Average` is an invalid column name and I cannot figure out why.  Also my `WHERE` has `Incorrect syntax near WHERE. Expecting AS, ID or QUOTED_ID` and `row_number` is `Invalid Column Name`.

As for query 4, my `AVG(UnitPrice)` throws an

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected

and again I'm lost and not sure why.

Query 3

```
SELECT 
    SupplierID, average
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT
         SupplierID, AVG(UnitPrice) average 
     FROM 
         Products 
     GROUP BY
         SupplierId 
     ORDER BY 
         average DESC)
WHERE 
    row_number <= 2
```

Query 4

```
SELECT TOP 3 
    Products.SupplierID AS SupplierID, AVG(UnitPrice) AVG_UnitPrice, 
    CompanyName, Phone 
FROM 
    Products 
JOIN
    Suppliers ON Products.SupplierID = Suppliers.SupplierID 
GROUP BY
    Products.SupplierID, CompanyName, Phone 
HAVING
    AVG(UnitPrice) >= 15 AND AVG(UnitPrice)
```

[SQL Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwFYC.png)

Comment: compare it with yours : http://rextester.com/GLCT79731

Answer (score 0):

**Query 3**

Try to give subquery a alias name

```
SELECT t1.SupplierID, t1.average
FROM (SELECT distinct SupplierID, AVG(UnitPrice) average FROM Products group 
by SupplierId order by average desc) as t1
WHERE row_number <= 2
```

**Query 4**

remove sql statement behind having `and AVG(UnitPrice)`

```
Select top 3 Products.SupplierID as SupplierID, AVG(UnitPrice) AS AVG_UnitPrice, CompanyName, Phone 
From Products join Suppliers on Products.SupplierID = Suppliers.SupplierID 
Group by Products.SupplierID, CompanyName, Phone 
having 
AVG(UnitPrice) >= 15
```

Answer (score 0):

**Query 3**

error means `row_number` column is not create in query , so here is the  solution

**Correct Sql Query**:

```
SELECT 
    SupplierID, average ,row_no
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT
         SupplierID, AVG(UnitPrice) average ,
         ROW_NUMBER()over (order by supplierid ) as row_no
     FROM 
         Products 
     GROUP BY
         SupplierId 
     ) temp
WHERE  row_no<= 2
ORDER BY average DESC
```

**Query 4**

`An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected`

Error means condition is required with last and clause

**Correct Sql Query** :

```
SELECT TOP 3 
    Products.SupplierID AS SupplierID, AVG(UnitPrice) AVG_UnitPrice, 
    CompanyName, Phone 
FROM 
    Products 
JOIN
    Suppliers ON Products.SupplierID = Suppliers.SupplierID 
GROUP BY
    Products.SupplierID, CompanyName, Phone 
HAVING
    AVG(UnitPrice) >= 15
```